# document.getElementById returns null with .sortable()

Tags: null, jquery-ui-sortable, getelementbyid

Script :

```
function initializeSort() {
    jQuery('#apps').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function () {
        // Save order in extension when apps are moved
        var children = document.getElementById("#apps").innerHTML;
        console.log(children);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            type: "updateApps",
            data: children
        });
    });
}
```

I get this error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

The only thing I can think of is that it's something to do with the `.sortable()` code I am using from here, http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/, because it works fine until I use `.sortable()` on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use jquery to get the children?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#apps').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function () {
     // Save order in extension when apps are moved
     var children = $("#apps").children();
     console.log(children);
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
         type: "updateApps",
         data: children
     });
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZuYpm/

Comment: thanks for reply.  When using jQuery I get this error when trying to send message with chrome api, Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 0):

No matter what I did it would always give me an element is null error or with jQuery a cannot convert circular object error.

I still don't understand why but after much hair pulling I was able to get it working with this,

```
jQuery('#apps').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function(){ 
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "updateApps", data: { list: jQuery("#apps").html()   } });
});
```

So for other people with the same problem I think the best way to send data through JSON is with an object or array of objects, you don't have to worry about types that way.